# jsdom parsing is extremely unstable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm scraping html docs with node+jsdom. But the same error message repeats itself again and again. Also the error message appears irregularly so I cannot figure what the problem is. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening?

```
var async = require("async"),
    jsdom = require("jsdom"),
    jsonfile = require("jsonfile"),
    scanf = require("scanf");


console.log("Input a json file name that includes uri codes");
var json_1st = scanf('%s');
var schCD = require('./json/'+ json_1st +'.json');

console.log("What kind of file?\n[1] A\n[2] B\n[3] C");
var selec_sch = scanf('%d');
if (selec_sch == 1){
    selec_sch = 9;
}else if(selec_sch == 2 ){
    selec_sch = 6;
}else if(selec_sch ==3 ){
    selec_sch = 12;
}else{console.log('Wrong Input. terminating process.');
                             process.exit(1);}

var times = 0;

//async start
async.mapSeries(schCD, function(item, callback){

//target page info
    jsdom.env(
        "http://www.schoolinfo.go.kr/ei/pp/Pneipp_b01_s0p.do?HG_NM=%B0%A5%BF%F8%C3%CA%B5%EE%C7%D0%B1%B3&HG_CD=" + item.HG_CD + "&GS_BURYU_CD=JG010&GS_HANGMOK_CD=01&JG_BURYU_CD=JG030&JG_HANGMOK_CD=62&JG_GUBUN=1&GS_HANGMOK_NO=3-1-1&GS_HANGMOK_NM=%C7%D0%B1%B3+%C7%F6%C8%B2&JG_YEAR2=2015&GS_TYPE=Y&JG_YEAR=2015&SORT=BR", 
        ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"],
        function(err, window){
          if(err) throw err;
          var $ = window.$;
          var tObj= $('table.TableType3 tbody tr:first-child td');

          console.log( "Name : " + item.HG_NM); // verifying stage
          console.log( "Code : " + item.HG_CD);
          var completeObj = {
                  "HG_name" : item.HG_NM,
                  "HG_CD"   : item.HG_CD
              };
          if(tObj[0]) {     // dealing with exception
                  completeObj.Gyowon = tObj[selec_sch].innerHTML;
              switch(selec_sch){
                  case 9 :
                      completeObj.G1 = tObj[0].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G2 = tObj[1].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G3 = tObj[2].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G4 = tObj[3].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G5 = tObj[4].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G6 = tObj[5].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.sp = tObj[7].innerHTML;

                  case 6 :
                      completeObj.G1 = tObj[0].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G2 = tObj[1].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G3 = tObj[2].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.sp = tObj[4].innerHTML;

                  case 12 :
                      var tObj = window.$('table.TableType3 tbody tr:eq(-2) td');
                      completeObj.G1 = tObj[0].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G2 = tObj[2].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.G3 = tObj[4].innerHTML;
                      completeObj.sp = tObj[6].innerHTML;
              }
              console.log( "Gyowon : " + completeObj.Gyowon);
              console.log(completeObj);
              if(completeObj.Gyowon) {console.log('---Loading Success---'); }
          }else{
              console.log('---No data---');
          }
          // showing progress
          times++;
          var procc = times/schCD.length*100;
          console.log('progress : ' + times + '/' + schCD.length + '(' + procc.toFixed(1) + '%)\n' );;
          callback(null, completeObj);
      });
}, function (err, result){
    console.log(result);
    console.log("parsing Ended. Writing son");
    jsonfile.writeFile('./completeDB/'+json_1st+'_gyoDB.json', result, {spaces: 4}, function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
    console.log('done');
    err && console.log(err);
});
```

This is the error message:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
    at Object.done (/Users/Snark/Dev/parsing/parsing_gyo.js:35:15)
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:271:18
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

Comment: How about posting the error message ?

Comment: ow I missed it! thanx

Comment: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs/